# Fletchers algorithm in Assembly

Tags: algorithm, assembly, arm, cortex-m

On a discoboard (ARM7) I'm attempting to implement fletcher's algorithm from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher%27s_checksum, and the input is a single 32 bit word.

Couldn't implement the 32 bit version of fletcher's as it required loading a huge number into memory so:

I'm splitting the 32 bit word into 2 16 bit half words, and then running the fletcher-16 algorithm.

However, the output is always the sum of the numbers instead, which seems very wrong to me.

eg,

```
Input: 0x1b84ccc / 1101110000100110011001100
```

Expected Output:

```
Checksum value
```

Real Output:

```
The sum of the 2 16 bit half words. Wut
```

Could anyone help if this is the actual algorithm, or have i made an error?

```
@ Input:
@ r0: 32 bit message
@ Output:
@ r0: checksum value
fletchers_checksum:
    push {r1-r4,lr}
    mov r3, #0 @ store the sum
    mov r4, r0 @ store message

    @split to 2 16 bit messages:
    @@take frequency
    ldr r1, =#0xFFFF0000
    and r0, r1, r4
    lsr r0, #16
    bl compute_checksum_for_16_bit_number

    @@amplitude
    ldr r1, =#0xFFFF
    and r0, r1, r4
    bl compute_checksum_for_16_bit_number

    mov r0, r3
    pop {r1-r3,lr}
    bx lr

compute_checksum_for_16_bit_number:
    push {lr}
    ldr r1, =#65536
    add r0, r3 @add current sum to it.
    bl mod
    mov r3, r0 @store new sum
    pop {lr}
    bx lr
```

Thank you!

Comment: you mean armv7?

Comment: Yes, apologies @old_timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the linked Wikipedia page:

> Usually, the second sum will be **multiplied by 2^16** and added to the
>   simple checksum, effectively stacking the sums side-by-side in a
>   32-bit word with the simple checksum at the least significant end.

Your code appears to calculate the two 16-bit checksums, but not to shift the second checksum by 16 bits as required.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you! :)